# how to decrement book quantity after successfully order is placed in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am trying to decrement the book quantity from my database table after the order is placed successfully.in the screenshot for book id 1 the book quantity is 5.so after placing order the book quantity should be 4. But how to do this code i am not getting. please help me

here is a screenshot of my database[image: screenshot]
`FileController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\Books as BooksResource;
use App\Models\Books;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function displayBooks()
    {
        $books=Books::all();
        return User::find($books->user_id=auth()->id())->books; 
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    function upload(Request $request){
        $book = new Books();
        $book->price=$request->input('price');
        $book->name=$request->input('name');
        $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
        $book->author=$request->input('author');
        $book->description=$request->input('description');
        $book->file=$request->input('file');
        $book->user_id = auth()->id();
        $book->save();
        return ["result"=>$book];
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function updateBook(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $book=Books::findorFail($id);
        if($book->user_id==auth()->id()){
            $book=Books::where('id',$id)
            ->update(array('name'=>$request->input('name'),
                            'price'=>$request->input('price'),
                            'author'=>$request->input('author'),
                            'quantity'=>$request->input('quantity'),
                            'description'=>$request->input('description')
            ));
        return['update book successfully'];
        }
    }
}
```

`CustomerController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Customers;
use App\Models\Orders;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Resources\Books;
use App\Models\Books as ModelsBooks;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Notifications\orderSuccessfullNotification;
use Illuminate\Support\Integer;

class CustomersController extends Controller
{
    public function customerRegistration(Request $request){
        $customer =new Customers();
        $customer->name=$request->input('name');
        $customer->phonenumber=$request->input('phonenumber');
        $customer->pincode=$request->input('pincode');
        $customer->locality=$request->input('locality');
        $customer->city=$request->input('city');
        $customer->address=$request->input('address');
        $customer->landmark=$request->input('landmark');
        $customer->type=$request->input('type');
        $customer->user_id = auth()->id();
        $customer->save();
    }

    public function orderSuccessfull(Request $request){
        $cust=new Customers();
        $cust->user_id = auth()->id();
        $cust_id=Customers::where('user_id',$cust->user_id)->value('user_id');
        $user_email=User::where('id',$cust_id)->value('email');
        $order = User::where('email', $user_email)->first();
        $ord = Orders::create(        
          [
              'orderNumber' => $order->orderNumber=mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999),
              'customer_id'=>$order->id,
              'order_date'=>$order->order_date=Carbon::now(),
          ]
        );
        if($order && $ord){
            $order->notify(new orderSuccessfullNotification($ord->orderNumber));
        }
        return response()->json(['message'=>'order created successfully','OrderId'=>$ord->orderNumber]);
    }
}
```

`Books_migration_table.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->string('file')->nullable();
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->enum('cart', [0, 1])->default(0);
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create an `Observer` for the `Order` model and whenever a order is successful/created you can decrement the books count.

Comment: Hi Sanchita, how do you identify the particular item that was ordered for in your orderSuccessfull() method? If you can identify the item from that method you can fetch and modify the quantity.